# How to update fields in salesforce objects after clicking on DocuSign button with content source URL

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a requirement regarding DocuSign salesforce. One DocuSign button has been created using DocuSign gen templates and that button has been placed in opportunity object. Button type is detail page and content source is URL. As the button is generated on runtime , it has already the URL CONTENT available [{!URLFOR(IF($Site.prefix == '/s','/apex/dfsle__gendocumentgenerator', $Site.Prefix +'/apex/dfsle__gendocumentgenerator'), null, [sId = Opportunity.Id, templateId = 'a0KAs000003F4b4MAC', recordId = Opportunity.Id, title = 'AAF-Template'])}].

But my requirement is to update few of the fields of opportunity (example : xyz__c,documentid__c) while clicking on the button. How do I do that?
Please help.

I was trying to modify the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the custom field of opportunity through URLFOR is more of Salesforce related question. I've found the below question from Stackoverflow that looks quite old but I think it could be the answer to your question: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xNxIAI